# Retrieve a set of posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a custom widget to show a custom set of posts in Wordpress by typing a comma separated list of post ids. The php I have to retrieve the posts is as follows:

```
<pre>
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $postid = get_the_ID();
  if ( strpos($instance['posts_ids'], (string)$postid) !== false ):
    show the post
</pre>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't always work. If my list of ids includes ID #12497 as one of them, this will retrieve that post, but might also retrieve a post with ID #249, because the string matches.

Any suggestions?

thanks
JA

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just find a string position successfully like that. Just explode + in_array in strict mode.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  $postid = get_the_ID();
  $ids = explode($instance['posts_ids'], ',');

  if ( in_array($ids, $postid, true) !== false ){
  [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to make it work using in_array. Thanks for your tip, it put me on the right path